# How do I boot from a USB drive recognized as fd0?

Tags: grub2, usb-drive, floppy

I am trying to boot Ubuntu Saucy from a USB stick that I created using the Startup Disk Creator Tool.

However, when I try to boot I just get a message `Boot error`.

I also have grub installed on a hard drive, so I tried going to the grub command line (with `c`) and found that grub sees my USB drive as a floppy (`fd0`) which I guess must be the problem. Running `ls (fd0)/` from the GRUB prompt lists nothing (even though there are definitely files there) and I have found no BIOS options that allow me to change this behavior in my BIOS.

Am I out of luck? Is there anything I can do to boot from this USB stick?

Extra info:

- My motherboard is a Gigabyte GA-M57SLI-S4.

Comment: Most likely you are seeing the actual floppy, not the flash drive.  Does it go away when you unplug the drive?

Comment: Yes, it does. I have the floppy drive disabled in BIOS. If I enable it, I see fd0 and fd1. As further confirmation, if I run `ls (fd0)` I see a vfat partition which is indeed what is on the USB stick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this isn't a perfect answer, but I read in the [GRUB manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Installing-GRUB-using-grub_002dinstall.html#Installing-GRUB-using-grub_002dinstall) about this issue affecting the *first partition*, so I tried creating two partitions on the USB drive. The BIOS still won't boot directly from the USB drive, but at least I can boot now using the hard drive's GRUB with:

```
linux (hd2,msdos2)/casper/vmlinuz.efi boot=casper
initrd (hd2,msdos2)/casper/initrd.lz
boot
```

I'll mark this as the answer unless someone else has a better answer in the next few weeks.

Comment: You can mark this as answer now